# Ajax request returns nothing. why?

Tags: php, ajax

Below is the ajax request.

```
$.post('delete.php', {'deletearray':deletearray, 'dir':dir}, function(deleted, undeleted){
    if(undeleted == 0) {
        alert('All ' + deleted + ' files delted from the server');
    } else {
        alert(deleted + ' files deleted and ' + undeleted + ' files could not be deleted');
    }
}, 'json');
```

and here goes the delete.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['deletearray'])) {
        $files = $_POST['deletearray'];
        $dir = $_POST['dir'];
        $deleted = 0;
        $undeleted = 0;

        foreach($files as $file) {
            if(unlink($dir.$file) && unlink($dir.'thumb/'.$file)) {
                $deleted ++;
            } else {
                $undeleted ++;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($deleted, $undeleted);
    }
    return;
?>
```

Up on running the code it deletes the files successfully but no message displays.

I also tried changing the ajax request as:

```
 $.post('delete.php', {deletearray:deletearray, dir:dir}, function(deleted, undeleted){
    alert("php finished");
 }, 'json');
```

still it does not display the message. So i guess something is wrong in the delete.php file. Please help.

Comment: If the problem is in PHP, why don't you check the error log? Or the javascript console too!

Comment: You're likely looking for `$_POST['deletearray']`, not `$_POST[deletearray]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do jquery + ajax + php is as next:

jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function do_ajax() { 
        //set data
        var myData  = new Array();
        myData.push({name:'deletearray',value:'deletearray'});
        myData.push({name:'dir',value:'dir'});
        //ajax post
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'delete.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: myData,
            success: function(returnData) {
                if(returnData.undeleted == 0) {
                    alert('All ' + returnData.deleted + ' files delted from the server');
                } else {
                    alert(returnData.deleted + ' files deleted and ' + returnData.undeleted + ' files could not be deleted');
                }
            }
        });
}            
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $myData = $_POST;
    if(isset($myData['deletearray']) AND isset($myData['dir'])) {
        $files = $myData['deletearray'];
        $dir = $myData['dir'];
        $deleted = 0;
        $undeleted = 0;

        foreach($files as $file) {
            if(unlink($dir.$file) && unlink($dir.'thumb/'.$file)) {
                $deleted ++;
            } else {
                $undeleted ++;
            }
        }
        print(json_encode(array('deleted' => $deleted, 'undeleted' => $undeleted)));
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing-

Use `$_POST['deletearray']` instead of `$_POST[deletearray]`

Second thing-

You cannot return different variables from the PHP scrtipt, every thing you print there is returned in the ajax callback, so just write this-

**PHP**

```
json_encode(array('totalDeleted' => $deleted, 'totalUndeleted' => $undeleted));
```

**AJAX**

```
...
function(response){
     response=JSON.parse(response);
     console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_encode` like following:

```
json_encode(array('deleted' => $deleted, 'undeleted' => $undeleted));
```

And you have to get vars with `data.undeleted` and `data.deleted`

```
$.post('delete.php', {'deletearray':deletearray, 'dir':dir}, function(data) {
    if(data.undeleted == 0) {
        alert('All ' + data.deleted + ' files delted from the server');
    } else {
        alert(data.deleted + ' files deleted and ' + data.undeleted + ' files could not be deleted');
    }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Your method will works, should be array. `json_encode($deleted, $undeleted)` was wrong

Comment: You are right. only array returns with json. Still my problem persists.