# Get data from mysql database using php and jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i  have create map using jvector map. Its Working well.Now i want country deatails from database . i have created php connection with mysql code

database.php

```
 <?php

    $host     = "localhost";
    $port     = 3306;
    $user     = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname   = "mydatabase";


    $country = $_POST['canada'];
    $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

    //$con->close();

    $query = "SELECT countryId, country, pdogcoregion, comments, ccl, category 
              FROM   countrydetails 
              WHERE  country='canada' ";
    $countrydetails = '';

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $countrydetails);

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($countryId, $country, $pdogcoregion, $comments, $ccl, $category);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        }

        $stmt->close();
    }

    ?>
```

here Is my html code:

```
  <script src="assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
      <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(function(){
          var $ = jQuery;
          $('#focus-single').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {region: 'AU', animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-multiple').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {regions: ['AU', 'JP'], animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-coords').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 7, lat: 35, lng: 33, animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-init').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 1, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, animate: true});
          });
          $('#map1').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            panOnDrag: true,
            focusOn: {
              x: 0.5,
              y: 0.5,
              scale: 1,
              animate: true
            },
            series: {
              regions: [{
                scale: ['#688FA0'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                values: {
              }]
            },
            onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
              var map = $('#map1').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
              var name = map.getRegionName(code);

              //alert(name);

              var labelText='Not Assign';

              // get from DB using ajax
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'database.php',
                data: {country: 'canada'},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data){
                  alert(data);
              });
           });
         });
```

how to connect ajax with mysql php database?please help..........

Comment: Here are some [basics](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: if your problem is how to make php+ajax (with db connection or not ,, it does not matter) you can check it here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24300581/3615630)

Comment: yes@MohammadAlabed sir.trying to connect php+ajax but its not connected sir ..

Comment: what part is failing? what is the error you are getting? And what have you tried so far to overcome your errors?

Comment: my error in ajax code if i check in mozila its showing alert box full php  database file.but i want diaplay data  from database

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo something out on database.php in order for the javascript to receive the result of the php actions. The format of the output can be what you want but it needs to be echoed or printed.